# How to get Page type of MainPage?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to know whether type of `MainPage` is `NavigationPage`, `MasterDetailPage` or etc?

`Application.Current.MainPage.GetType()` gets the class name but not the page type.

Comment: with `is` like this => `Application.Current.MainPage is NavigationPage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @apineda said `is` is the solution, like this => `Application.Current.MainPage is NavigationPage`.